# golang: how to use make() function to generate 2-demensional slice?

Tags: go, makefile, initialization, 2d, slice

First I declared variable `p` in one place:

```
var p [2][]int
```

It's a 2d slice, and size of each dimension should be dynamically determined at run time.

Then in another function, I tried to initialize `p`:

```
    n1 := ...
    n2 := ...
    p = make([][]int, 2) // syntax error
    p[0] = make([]int, n1) // ok
    p[1] = make([]int, n2) // ok
```

The syntax error is:

```
cannot use make([][]int, 2) (value of type [][]int) as [2][]int value in assignment(compiler)
```

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: The `2` in `var p [2][]int` means that `p` is an **array** (not a slice) with **two** `[]int` (integer slice) elements inside, never more, never less. In Go array's size is determined at **compile time**, NOT run-time. In Go arrays are constant while slices are dynamic. In Go `[N]T` is and array, `[]T` is a slice, two distinct types. You cannot assign an instance of one to the other. Do not confuse them. *(and btw. the `N` in `[N]T` **cannot** be a variable, it MUST be an integer constant known at compile time)*

Comment: https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of `p` here indicates a 2D array. You can convert it to a 2D Slice:

```
var p [][]int
```

This should then work as expected when allocation is done via `make()`.